# Midnight last Monday in Powershell

Tags: date, powershell, time

I'm trying to hack up a script that returns the amount of email received to and sent from certain mailboxes today, this week and this month.  I wrote this and felt good about myself until I realised my logic was wrong and it was returning the last 24 hours (get-date.(adddays(-1)) and last 7 consecutive 24 hour periods (get-date.adddays(-7)) etc.

Figuring out the first day of the month to count from wasn't that hard, found a snippet to copy

```
$firstDayOfMonth = Get-Date ((("01/" + (Get-Date $today).Month).ToString() + "/" + ((Get-Date $today).Year).ToString() + " 00:00:00"))
```

which starts with 01/ and adds today's month and years as string then appends midnight time and bundles the whole thing into a system.time object, but I can't do that with the week.

System.time objects have a .DayOfWeek property and I can switch that to figure out how many days we are from last Monday, and I have a $Monday variable that contains **this time last Monday**, how do I modify that variable to refer to **midnight** last Monday?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### First Monday of the Month

```
do {
    $n++
    $date = (date -Hour 0 -Minute 0 -Second 0).AddDays(-$n)
}
Until ( `
    $date.DayOfWeek -eq "Monday" -and `
    $date.Day -le 7 `
)
```

### First Monday of the Week

```
$n = 0
do {
    $date = (date -Hour 0 -Minute 0 -Second 0).AddDays(-$n)
    $n++
}
Until ( $date.DayOfWeek -eq "Monday" )
```

Comment: Lovely script.  Does it need $n=0 at the very start, and $Date at the very end, or am I just stating the obvious?

Comment: `$n++` will initialize the variable with a value of `1`, so that is okay there. Also, yes, `$date` would need to be on the end if you wanted to write it to the console. We probably don't even need the `TimeOfDay` bit either, since I already specified the params in the date command.

Comment: That's awesome, but your comment says the first Monday of the month, I'm after the first Monday of the **week**, but reading your code I think that's what it does?  Wind the clock back until it's Midnight Monday?

As a side issue, this works great dumped into a PS1 file on my computer but on the server that does the reports I get "A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Millisecond'."  - is there something I haven't included or a version mismatch of powershell?

Comment: I just tested it on PS v2, it doesn't have millisecond... So You might have to deal with 0-999 milliseconds of inaccuracy :P

Answer (score 9):

maybe, this is your friend:

```
([int](Get-date).DayOfWeek)
```

This converts the DayOfWeek-property to the numeral-day of the week ...

For Example:

```
(Get-Date 0:00).AddDays(-([int](Get-date).DayOfWeek)+1)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can calculate the date of last Monday like this:

```
$today = Get-Date
$delta = $today.DayOfWeek.value__ - 1

$today.AddDays(-$delta).Date
```

The `Date` property returns the date with the time set to 00:00:00, so you don't need to calculate the time.

Note that on Mondays the above code returns the current date. If you want the code to return the previous Monday you need to change the second line to this:

```
$delta = ($today.DayOfWeek.value__ + 5) % 7 + 1
```

The first day of the month can be calculated in a similar manner:

```
$today = Get-Date
$delta = $today.Day - 1

$today.AddDays(-$delta).Date
```

Comment: While this is very similar to Jan's answer I think it's the clearest.  It's easy to understand what's going on here.

Answer (score 5):

Sunday of this week (Assuming weeks start on Sunday):

```
$sunday = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1 * (Get-Date).DayOfWeek.Value__).Date
```

Monday of this week:

```
$monday = (Get-Date).AddDays((-1 * (Get-Date).DayOfWeek.Value__) + 1).Date
```

Tuesday of this week:

```
$tuesday = (Get-Date).AddDays((-1 * (Get-Date).DayOfWeek.Value__) + 2).Date
```

Etc. etc. for Wed - Sat

Answer (score 2):

got this one working for any day:

```
((Get-Date).adddays(-(6+(Get-Date -UFormat %u)))).date
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$i=0
do { $LastMonday = (Get-Date).AddDays(--$i).Date }
until ( $LastMonday.DayofWeek -eq 'Monday' )

$LastMonday

Monday, February 03, 2014 12:00:00 AM
```

The Date proptery of a DateTime object is the datetime on Midnight of that day.